# adding color in bar plot and lumping data

Tags: r, visualization

I would like to ask how to add color to a bar plot (first question) and how to lump data value into one (second question)

(First question)
I tried to add color using "col" function, but there are no changes to the color.

```
ggplot(group.emission, aes(x= reorder(Emission_class, -emission_median), y=emission_median), col= c("lightgreen", "blue", "red", "yellow"), fill=position) + labs(title= "Four main vehicle clusters, by carbon emission") + labs(y="Carbon emision (median)", x = "clusters")
```

Output:
[image]

I have also tried geom_bar. However, it features a legend that I don't want to. Therefore, I would like to ask how can I add color to the bar plot and not create any legend.

```
ggplot(group.emission, aes(x= reorder(Emission_class, -emission_median), y=emission_median, fill= Emission_class)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

[image]

(second question)

I would like to only show the first 10 variables (x-axis) and lump the rest into "others". But I am not sure how can I do so.

```
electrical$Brand <- factor(electrical$Brand) %>% fct_infreq ()
ncolor <-length(unique(electrical$Brand))
fcolors <-colorRampPalette(c("dark blue", "white"))
plot(electrical$Brand, las=2, ylim=c(0,30), cex.axis=0.5, cex=0.5, col=fcolors(ncolor))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the `diamonds` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

# define palette 
sPalette <- c("Purples") %>% 
  sapply(., function(x) brewer.pal(8, name = x)) %>% 
  as.vector

# data wrangling and plot
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(clarity = fct_lump(clarity, n = 5)) %>% 
  count(clarity) %>% 
  mutate(clarity = fct_reorder(clarity, n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(clarity, n, fill=clarity)) +
  geom_col(color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sPalette) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=rev)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]